# remove or hide element with specific class which is not part of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

let say an array contains elements "socket io ids":
 `["Uv1E69LxlAE0Ux9iAAAB","Fm4EVQIoUM7O_JdvAAAI"]` , in the html page there are elements like:

```
<li class="p-mfq6XcxKLpuOf0AAAH">some data1</li>
<li class="Uv1E69LxlAE0Ux9iAAAB">some data2</li>
<li class="Fm4EVQIoUM7O_JdvAAAI">some data3</li>
```

I'm looking to remove or addClass to the first element which its class is not part of the array

Comment: So do it.  Otherwise, what is your question about how to do this?

Comment: Hello Hisham. Please show us what you have tried so far and we'll help you from there.

Comment: Would be cleaner to store those values in a data attribute rather than as a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it very easily using `.filter()` that filtered elements. In function use `.indexOf()` to checking that element class exist in array or not.

```js
var arr = ["Uv1E69LxlAE0Ux9iAAAB","Fm4EVQIoUM7O_JdvAAAI"];

$("ul li").filter(function(){
  return arr.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) == -1;
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="p-mfq6XcxKLpuOf0AAAH">some data1</li>
  <li class="Uv1E69LxlAE0Ux9iAAAB">some data2</li>
  <li class="Fm4EVQIoUM7O_JdvAAAI">some data3</li>
</ul>
```